# Can I install drywall on energy walls left by the builder?

Tags: basement

Within our new house, builder insulated the basement. To hold the insulation, builder did install framing to hold R22 insulation. This is then wrapped by a plastic wrap (I believe it is vapour barrier).

To finish my basement, can I install drywall on the same framing as installed by the builder? Or do I need to frame in front of builder provided (this does mean I lose ~6" per side)?

Thanks.

Comment: picture will help.  a service wall is nice but you wouldn't go 2x6 for a service wall, 2x4 at most, depends if you want to put outlets / plumbing in the wall.

Answer (score 2):

You don't describe the framing at all, but let's assume that it has top and bottom plates and studs at 16" or 24" intervals. If so, then the walls were intended to be finished. Double check that the plates are fastened securely to the floor slab and ceiling framing and carry on.

Of course, you may need to drop the plastic to run wiring. You might also verify that any window openings are framed properly for your trim plans.

If you have something else it'll probably require enhancement before hanging drywall.